# Postgresql - archive_command Windows, not working

Tags: postgresql, archive

I'm attempting to set up archiving on a windows server machine but when I check the logs nothing is happening.

The postgresql.conf file this is my input:

```
#wal_level = replica

#archive_mode = on
#archive_command = 'copy "%p" "\\172.27.193.28\temp\archivedir\\%f"' 
also tried this
#archive_command = 'copy "%p" "c:\\temp\archivedir\\%f"'

#archive_timeout = 0
```

Any ideas why this isn't archiving?

Answer (score 1):

The `#` at the beginning of a line means it's a comment. Those lines aren't doing anything.

You need to use:

```
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'copy "%p" "c:\\temp\archivedir\\%f"'
```

Note, there is no `#` at the beginning of the line.

`wal_level = replica` is only needed for the master, not the replica.